# Python to SQL Server connection

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pypyodbc

I'm using Python 3.5.1 with Anaconda package 2.4.0 and try to make a connection to local SQL Server (2008 R2)

So doing the next things:

```
import pypyodbc
connection_string =pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=PC\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Database=localbase;Uid=name;Pwd=pass')
connection_string=connection_string.decode(encodind='utf-8',errors='replace')
```

After all the manipulations, receive the error:

```
'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated data
```

Why's that and what should I perform to avoid it and run the connection properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what a "connection string" is. It is the text string that you *pass to* the `.connect` method, not what is *returned from* the `.connect` method. (What gets returned is a `connection` object.)

So, you need to do something more like this:

```python
import pypyodbc
connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER= ...(and so on)..."
conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)
crsr = conn.cursor()
crsr.execute("SELECT stuff FROM tablename")
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='servername', user='username', 
password='password', database='databasename')
print("Connected to Database")
```

***Use this string connection to connect do database :)***

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.